# Trigger an SVG animation on SVG hover

Tags: animation, svg

I have a logo made of SVG. 
This logo is made of a few paths, two of them have an animation with different timing.
How do I trigger their animation when the SVG is hovered?
I mean, I need both of the animations to run when the entire SVG is hovered.

Here's a CodePen of what I have so far:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbByYE.

Here's the entire code:

```css
svg {
  width: 160px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <path id="shape1" fill="#f42b38" d="M77.6,67.9v0.4c0.1,0.7,0.5,1.4,1.1,1.9l2.8,2.1c1.2,0.9,3.1,0.7,4-0.6c4.7-6.3,7.2-13.8,7.2-21.5
      s-2.5-15.2-7.2-21.5c-0.9-1.2-2.7-1.5-4-0.6L78.8,30c-0.6,0.4-1,1.1-1.1,1.9v0.4c0,0.6,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.7c3.5,4.7,5.3,10.3,5.3,16
      s-1.9,11.3-5.3,16C77.9,66.7,77.6,67.3,77.6,67.9z ">
        
    <animateTransform  
                      type="rotate" 
                      fill="remove" 
                      restart="always" 
                      to="360 57 50" 
                      from="0 57 50" 
                      dur="0.7s" 
                      begin="0.15s" 
                      calcMode="spline" 
                      additive="replace"
                      accumulate="none" 
                      attributeName="transform" 
                      attributeType="xml" 
                      keySplines="0.42 0 0.58 1" 
                      rotate="10; 100" 
                      repeatCount="1" 
                      keyTimes="0; 1">
       </animateTransform>
        
      </path>
     <path id="shape2" fill="#f42b38" d="M65.9,59.4v0.4c0.1,0.7,0.5,1.4,1.1,1.9l2.3,1.6c1.2,0.9,3,0.7,4-0.6
      c5.3-7.1,5.3-18.1,0-25.2c-0.9-1.2-2.7-1.5-4-0.6L67,38.5c-0.6,0.4-1,1.1-1.1,1.9v0.4c0,0.6,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.7c3.2,4.2,3.2,10.8,0,15
      C66.1,58.1,65.9,58.7,65.9,59.4z ">
    <animateTransform  
                      type="rotate" 
                      fill="remove" 
                      restart="always" 
                      to="360 57 50" 
                      from="0 57 50" 
                      dur="0.85s" 
                      calcMode="spline" 
                      additive="replace" 
                      accumulate="none" 
                      attributeName="transform" 
                      attributeType="xml" 
                      keySplines="0 0 0.58 1" 
                      rotate="10; 100" 
                      repeatCount="1" 
                      keyTimes="0; 1">
       </animateTransform>
     </path>
     <path fill="#f42b38" d="M90.7,78.6c-1.2-1.2-3.1-1.2-4.3,0c-7.6,7.5-17.6,11.7-28.3,11.7C36,90.3,18,72.3,18,50.2
      s18-40.1,40.1-40.1c10.6,0,20.7,4.1,28.3,11.7c1.2,1.1,3.1,1.1,4.3,0l2.7-2.7c1.1-1.1,1.1-3.2,0-4.3C83.9,5.3,71.5,0.1,58.2,0.1
      c-27.6,0-50,22.4-50,50s22.4,50,50,50c13.3,0,25.8-5.1,35.3-14.6c1.1-1.1,1.1-3.2,0-4.3L90.7,78.6z"/>
     <path fill="#f42b38" d="M53.2,50.1c0,2.6,2.2,4.7,4.7,4.7c2.6,0,4.7-2.2,4.7-4.7s-2.2-4.7-4.8-4.7C55.2,45.4,53.2,47.5,53.2,50.1z"
      />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change the `begin` attributes to `indefinite` so that the animation doesn't run straight away. Then use the mouseover event to trigger the animations when required.

For example (assuming `trans1` and `trans2` are the IDs assigned to the two animated elements):

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('trans2').beginElement();setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'trans1\').beginElement()',150);"
```

One slight problem is that the mouseover event will trigger for each individual element of the SVG object, which you probably don't want. You can fix this by putting a transparent rect over the entire drawing to capture all the mouse events.

See the snippet below for a working example.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="document.getElementById('trans2').beginElement();setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'trans1\').beginElement()',150);">
<g>
  <path id="shape1" fill="#f42b38" d="M77.6,67.9v0.4c0.1,0.7,0.5,1.4,1.1,1.9l2.8,2.1c1.2,0.9,3.1,0.7,4-0.6c4.7-6.3,7.2-13.8,7.2-21.5
        s-2.5-15.2-7.2-21.5c-0.9-1.2-2.7-1.5-4-0.6L78.8,30c-0.6,0.4-1,1.1-1.1,1.9v0.4c0,0.6,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.7c3.5,4.7,5.3,10.3,5.3,16
        s-1.9,11.3-5.3,16C77.9,66.7,77.6,67.3,77.6,67.9z    ">

<animateTransform id="trans1"
                  type="rotate" 
                  fill="remove" 
                  restart="always" 
                  to="360 57 50" 
                  from="0 57 50" 
                  dur="0.7s" 
                  begin="indefinite" 
                  calcMode="spline" 
                  additive="replace"
                  accumulate="none" 
                  attributeName="transform" 
                  attributeType="xml" 
                  keySplines="0.42 0 0.58 1" 
                  rotate="10; 100" 
                  repeatCount="1" 
                  keyTimes="0; 1">
            </animateTransform>

  </path>
    <path id="shape2" fill="#f42b38" d="M65.9,59.4v0.4c0.1,0.7,0.5,1.4,1.1,1.9l2.3,1.6c1.2,0.9,3,0.7,4-0.6
        c5.3-7.1,5.3-18.1,0-25.2c-0.9-1.2-2.7-1.5-4-0.6L67,38.5c-0.6,0.4-1,1.1-1.1,1.9v0.4c0,0.6,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.7c3.2,4.2,3.2,10.8,0,15
        C66.1,58.1,65.9,58.7,65.9,59.4z ">
<animateTransform id="trans2"
                  type="rotate" 
                  fill="remove" 
                  restart="always" 
                  to="360 57 50" 
                  from="0 57 50" 
                  dur="0.85s" 
                  begin="indefinite"
                  calcMode="spline" 
                  additive="replace" 
                  accumulate="none" 
                  attributeName="transform" 
                  attributeType="xml" 
                  keySplines="0 0 0.58 1" 
                  rotate="10; 100" 
                  repeatCount="1" 
                  keyTimes="0; 1">
            </animateTransform>
    </path>
    <path fill="#f42b38" d="M90.7,78.6c-1.2-1.2-3.1-1.2-4.3,0c-7.6,7.5-17.6,11.7-28.3,11.7C36,90.3,18,72.3,18,50.2
        s18-40.1,40.1-40.1c10.6,0,20.7,4.1,28.3,11.7c1.2,1.1,3.1,1.1,4.3,0l2.7-2.7c1.1-1.1,1.1-3.2,0-4.3C83.9,5.3,71.5,0.1,58.2,0.1
        c-27.6,0-50,22.4-50,50s22.4,50,50,50c13.3,0,25.8-5.1,35.3-14.6c1.1-1.1,1.1-3.2,0-4.3L90.7,78.6z"/>
    <path fill="#f42b38" d="M53.2,50.1c0,2.6,2.2,4.7,4.7,4.7c2.6,0,4.7-2.2,4.7-4.7s-2.2-4.7-4.8-4.7C55.2,45.4,53.2,47.5,53.2,50.1z"
        />
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="#fff" opacity="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

The existing answer seems a bit more difficult than it needs to be. What I found was that an animate tag inside an svg can have begin="mouseover"

```
<animate
  attributename=""
  from=""
  to=""
  begin="mouseover"
  dur=""
/>
```

this sets the animation in motion whenever the svg element is hovered over. there are lots of other event types I didn't know about that you can find here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin